# non-WPF instance callback to a WPF-Control derived class. Change DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, callback, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

1. **WPF control-derived class** has a composition of **non-WPF control-derived class**. The latter class, say *Inner*, should trigger an Outer class WPF DependencyProperty change.
2. Essential invariant is that **my *Inner* class shouldn't force any WPF namespaces to use** whereby, *Inner* is part of API of a dll I am creating. So Inheritance from any WPF class is not appropriate solution.

*What could be the best (or at least arbitraty) way to implement a callback from non-.NET derived class to a WPF-Control class to change a DependencyProperty object.*

Some hypothetical callback mechanisms found:

- **c# delegates and c# events**.

Can't solve this, becouce it is thrown a runtime exception

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

when a callback mechanism tries to modify Background property (a DependancyProperty object I think is the key, or at least .NET defined property).

I guess that c# delegates doesn't work in single-threading manner - however, i didn't find this fact while reading c# documentation.

(One solution is through .NET Dispatcher class and Invoke(), but it seems too arbitrary and possibly slow - isn't any more WPF-friendly way?)

- I had read about **Routed events and DependencyProperties**

in WPF documentation (however had't tested this yet), but it seems Routed event cant help (because my *Inner* class isn't part of a VisualTree) and I should't inherit from DependencyObject.

I read (I suppose) everything relevant to my problem. I'm sorry if some similar kind of question had been asked, I would be glad if you direct me to that thread, if the problem essence is the same.

Simplified example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Timers;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    internal class Rect:ContentControl
    {
        Inner inner = new Inner();

        public Rect()
        {
            inner.Rotate += new Inner.RotateEventHandler(rotated);
        }

        public void rotated(object sender, RotateEventArgs args)
        {
            Background = Brushes.Blue;                            //Run time error
            VisualTransform = new RotateTransform(args.Angle);  //Run time error
        }
    }

    public class Inner
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(200);

        public Inner()
        {
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Elapsed +=new ElapsedEventHandler(elapsed);
        }

        public delegate void RotateEventHandler(object sender, RotateEventArgs args);
        public event RotateEventHandler Rotate;

        public void elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            RotateEventArgs args = new RotateEventArgs();
            args.Angle = args.Angle + 45;
            OnRotate(args);
        }

        protected void OnRotate(RotateEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e != null)
            {
                Rotate(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class RotateEventArgs
    {
        private double angle = 0;

        public double Angle
        {
            set { angle = value; }
            get { return angle; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`DispatchTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) instead of `Timer`. Have the `DispatchTimer` in the `Rect` class itself.